# Android Get Gender Google Sign-In when marked Private - How does medium do it?

Tags: android, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I have tried almost all solutions everywhere, but at no place I am able to get user gender information if its marked as private, even if it requesting user to provide access to gender.

I have seen medium & various other apps do it using contacts. How can we do it or if I have missed something in above, do tell.

Comment: What are you getting currently for "value" key now in case of private?

Comment: I have tried multiple experiments/apis some of which return null and some return '0' even for female. Simply changing the gender visibility to public(on google account), lets me get correct values.